# I need help creating a regex for Python

Tags: python, regex, variables

I need a regex for capturing **_0x263E9[digit]** specifically.

I do not want to replace anything else, does anyone have any idea of the best way to tackle this. I have used regex101 for help but I can't seem to do it

```
''' _0x264A5(_0x26503) 
    0x26503(_0x263E9[37])[_0x263E9[36]](_0x263E9[12], function () {
        var _0x265BF = _0x263E9[13],
            _0x26561 = _0x263E9[14],
            _0x26795 = window[_0x263E9[15]];
        if (new RegExp(_0x263E9[17])[_0x263E9[16]](_0x26795)) {
            for (var _0x2667B = document[_0x263E9[19]](_0x263E9[18]), _0x266D9 = 0; _0x266D9 < _0x2667B[_0x263E9[5]]; _0x266D9++) {
                if (_0x2667B[_0x266D9][_0x263E9[20]][_0x263E9[5]] > 0) {
                    var _0x2661D = _0x2667B[_0x266D9][_0x263E9[21]];
                    _0x263E9[13] == _0x2661D && (_0x2661D = _0x266D9), _0x265BF += _0x2661D + _0x263E9[3] + _0x2667B[_0x266D9][_0x263E9[20]] + _0x263E9[22]'''
```

Comment: Did you try: `r'_0x263E9\[\d+\]'`?

Comment: Once you have "captured" it, what do you want to do with it? @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ 's regex finds 18 matches.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour. Valid SO question. End of reviewing. Enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank for @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ and you already got the point.

try [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) : return a list of groups.

regex for capturing _0x263E9[digit]:

```
re.findall(r'_0x263E9\[\d+\]', str)
```

or retrieving the digits only

```
re.findall(r'_0x263E9\[\(d+)\]', str)
```